# Word to describe remembering some text

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I am reading Chapter 1 very loudly in order to remember the text because tomorrow I need to ____ it [read the text without open the book] in front of my teacher.

Comment: Are you looking for the word _memorize_ (as your question header suggests) or a word such as _recite/repeat/declaim_ (as the body of your question suggests)?

Comment: What @SvenYargs said. It's so annoying when the title and the body ask for entirely different things.

Comment: You need to "commit the material to memory" and then "recite it, by heart" to the teacher.  Both phrases in quotes are idiomatic phrases that I'm assuming will cover the whole process you described in your question.  You should be able to Google these phrases to get a better understanding of how they're used: "commit to memory", "recite by heart"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Recite](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/recite)**, especially for poems or plays. Or, as suggested, repeat/present.

By the way, are you reading *loudly* (i.e. at high volume) or *out loud* (i.e. saying the words and not just reading in your mind?). If I have to prepare a talk in front of a class, I read *out loud*, but I can simply whisper, I don't need to shout.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use to ***repeat***

> - *To recite from memory*: repeated the poem verbatim.

(AHD)

Answer (score -1):

You need to **rehearse**/repeat it tomorrow.

As in [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rehearse), *rehearse* means:

> 1. To practice (a part in a play or a piece of music, for example) in preparation for a public performance
> 2. To practice (an action) by repetition so as to improve performance
> 3. To repeat or recite

**E.g.** *Typically I **rehearse my presentation** during flights. My sister seems to be packed already I notice, and taking advantage of her organization...*